# WPF Binding nightmares

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, itemssource

So I have a Class

```
public class ObjectDataModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ObjectClassA> MyObjectCollection;
}

public class ObjectClassA
{
    public ObjecttypeA myobject;
    public BitmapImage mybmp;
}
```

Now I have a grid control whose *`ItemsSource`* I wish to bind to *`myObject`* of *`MyObjectCollection`*.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You must expose ur binding target as **Properties** not as *Fields* (like you currently do).

```
<Window>
<Window.DataContext><local:ObjectDataModel/></Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
<ListView ItemsSource={Binding MyObjectCollection}/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: To expand on this, those properties need getters & setters and any data you expect to change needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise the PropertyChanged event so the databinding knows to update the value.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to achieve this, if yes then it will be great if you can post your XAML code.

As per my understanding this is the correct way of using this class -

```
    <ItemsControl
        Margin="5,0,5,5"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyObjectCollection}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid >
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Margin="0,5,0,0"
                        Width="Auto"
                        Text="{Binding Path=myobject.Property1}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```